# How to Test Stripe Webhooks with Mock Data

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm trying to write a unit test that posts a mock event to my stripe webhook.

I went and pulled an event from my logs and tried sending that with the test mode enabled, but I (somewhat predictably) got an error:

> a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.

Fair enough. So how do I create a mock event that I can actually send to my webhook and get it processed correctly?

Here's my current test:

```
class StripeTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_receiving_a_callback(self):
        with open('donate/test_assets/stripe_event.json', 'r') as f:
            stripe_event = simplejson.load(f)

        self.client.post('/donate/callbacks/stripe/',
                         data=simplejson.dumps(stripe_event),
                         content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to create your own mock data. In the code below we create a test payment by creating a stripe token, then submitting it via the front end (at the /donate/ endpoint).

Once the front end has worked properly, you can get the event from stripe and then send it to your development machine's webhook endpoint.

This is more work than I expected, and I don't love that my tests are hitting the network, but it seems to be a decent solution. I feel a lot more confident about my payments than before.

```
    def test_making_a_donation_and_getting_the_callback(self):
        """These two tests must live together because they need to be done sequentially.

        First, we place a donation using the client. Then we send a mock callback to our
        webhook, to make sure it accepts it properly.
        """
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        # Create a stripe token (this would normally be done via javascript in the front
        # end when the submit button was pressed)
        token = stripe.Token.create(
            card={
                'number': '4242424242424242',
                'exp_month': '6',
                'exp_year': str(datetime.today().year + 1),
                'cvc': '123',
            }
        )

        # Place a donation as an anonymous (not logged in) person using the
        # token we just got
        r = self.client.post('/donate/', data={
            'amount': '25',
            'payment_provider': 'cc',
            'first_name': 'Barack',
            'last_name': 'Obama',
            'address1': '1600 Pennsylvania Ave.',
            'address2': 'The Whitehouse',
            'city': 'DC',
            'state': 'DC',
            'zip_code': '20500',
            'email': 'barack@freelawproject.org',
            'referrer': 'footer',
            'stripeToken': token.id,
        })

        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 302)  # 302 because we redirect after a post.

        # Get the stripe event so we can post it to the webhook
        # We don't know the event ID, so we have to get the latest ones, then filter...
        events = stripe.Event.all()
        event = None
        for obj in events.data:
            if obj.data.object.card.fingerprint == token.card.fingerprint:
                event = obj
                break
        self.assertIsNotNone(event, msg="Unable to find correct event for token: %s" % token.card.fingerprint)

        # Finally, we can test the webhook!
        r = self.client.post('/donate/callbacks/stripe/',
                             data=simplejson.dumps(event),
                             content_type='application/json')

        # Does it return properly?
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
```